# Ajax 405 (Method Not Allowed) when I action field is blank or same as current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First off thanks to @abc123 for the code below as I found this on one of his posts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="formoid" action="" title="" method="post">
        <div>
            <label class="title">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="title">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit">
        </div>
 </form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      /* get some values from elements on the page: */
      var $form = $( this ),
          url = $form.attr( 'action' );

      /* Send the data using post */
      var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), name2: $('#name2').val() } );

      /* Alerts the results */
      posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('posting');
      });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have made a slight amend as I want to submit the form to the page on which it sits, but when I do, I get `405 (Method Not Allowed)` when I look in Developer Tools. I know this is because the `action=""` is null, but is there a way round this?

Comment: If posting url is empty where you want to post?

Comment: I want the form to submit to the current page. So index.html will submit the form to index.html. Using Classic ASP to submit the form this works.

Comment: so mention 'index.aspx' or whatever you want. You'll get the data on other side(Server). I don't know more about aspx, but in `MVC`, you can give `'Controller/Action'` name in your page and then it will be submitted to that controller action

Answer (score 0):

The `url` variable is empty. Try replace line 
 `url = $form.attr( 'action' );` 
with 
`url =  $form.attr('action') == '' ? window.location : $form.attr('action');`